# socket-io usernames and connected client list

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I've got a question regarding client-management socket.io with node.js

I'm running a very basic socket.io application where several socket.io-clients connect to a socket.io-server. When I try to populate a list of clients I do it like this:

server.js:

```
 var clients = [];
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.emit('whoareyou');
            socket.on('hithere', function(name){
                    clients.push(name);
                    socket.emit('clients', clients);
                    console.log(name+" connected");
                    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                            console.log(name+" disconnected");
                            clients.splice(clients.indexOf(name), 1);
                    });
            });
    });
```

clients.js

```
var socket = io.connect(server, {
    port: 80
  });

  socket.on('whoareyou', function(){
        socket.emit('hithere',hostname);
  });
});
```

The clients-emit is for a webpage to populate the client-list because I don't really know how to exchange this list with a webserver running on the same machine without emitting.

Now, what I could do is skipping this whole whoareyou and hithere-crap and saving the socket as a JSON-array in clients. The ugly detail about this is that I just want to use the hostname of the client as a nickname and this is not a part of the socket-JSON (btw: the ip-address is part of it).

the socket-io docs show  a nice example of a chat-room here: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ but the interesting parts are left out.

Does somebody know a nice way how to do this?

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: well, I want to transport the hostname within the connection-event but somehow I don't know how.

Comment: By hostname you mean `location.hostname`?

Comment: You can use `socket.handshake.headers.host`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Farid, sorry for my late answer. socket.handshake.headers.host gave me the hostname of the machine running server.js . What I want to get is the hostname of each connected client running on other machines.

Comment: How do you get that in javascript?

Comment: running socket.io-client I can read the hostname of a machine with os.hostname(). Did you mean how I used socket.handshake.headers.host? I read out the socket-object on the server that has been transferred by the client. I can read the ip-address and a lot of other things but not the hostname.

Comment: There's no os.hostname() in client side javascript...

Comment: Yes it is. There are two machines. One running socket.io and one running socket.io-client. On the client machine I can get the machines hostname by var os = require("os"); and then hostname = os.hostname(); What I wanted was to pass the hostname when transferring the socket-object.